# DatetimePicker Format

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I try to get `04/04/2017 - 14:58` date format when I select a date and an hour:

But actually with this form:

```
<div class="input-group date form_datetime">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="datetime" name="datetime" class="form-control pull-right">
</div><!-- /.input group -->
```

I get `04 April 2017 - 14:58`

I don't know how to change this! For info I use `AdminLTE` for `laravel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `format` when calling datepicker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      format: "DD/MM/YYYY h:mm"
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the issue is caused by the "datepicker" plugin used by AdminLTE. You can try to modify the returned date format that set. Which plugin that they use? Is it bootstrap-datepicker? Here's their official document: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#